# Remove empty space on highcharts column chart left side

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to remove the empty space at the left of the chart. 
Have found no solution so far.

OK so i want all the columns to be placed on the right side of the ticks as in the fiddle, and remove the empty space between the y axis and the first tick.
Thanks in advance

```js
$(function() {
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Efficiency Optimization by Branch'
    },
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: [{
      min: 0,
    }],
    series: [{
      name: 'Employees',
      color: 'rgba(165,170,217,1)',
      data: [150, 73, 20],
      pointPadding: 0.3,
      pointPlacement: 0.25
    }, {
      name: 'Employees Optimized',
      color: 'rgba(126,86,134,.9)',
      data: [140, 90, 40],
      pointPadding: 0.3,
      pointPlacement: 0.10
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what you want. If you mean the space to the left of each category label, you are telling the chart to add it by your `pointPlacement` settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts remove gap between start of xAxis and first value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593883/highcharts-remove-gap-between-start-of-xaxis-and-first-value)

Comment: Try to set pointPlacement to 'on' and set xAxis min explicitly - see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4v9dhsry/1/)

Comment: OK so i want all the columns to be placed on the right side of the ticks as in the fiddle, and rmove the empty space between the y axis and the first tick. Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-grouppadding-none/). This will remove all side spaces and give equal padding.