# Ugly Highchart when using letter label for both xaxis and yaxis

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, highcharts

I am trying to make the chart with both text label on xAxis and yAxis like this

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTG6x.png)

I am able to make it by this configuration

```
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('chart-container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar',
    },
    title: {
      text: '',
      floating: true
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.2f}</b><br/>'
    },
    xAxis: {
      gridLineColor: '#7F7F7F',
      lineColor: '#7F7F7F',
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      tickLength: 0,
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        reserveSpace: true
      },
      categories: ['1. - 4. trinn (frivillige øvelser)', '1. - 4. trinn (obligatorisk ferdighetsprøve)', '5. - 7. trinn (frivillige øvelser)', '8. - 10. trinn (frivillige øvelser)']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 31.83333,
      max: 100,
      title: {
        text: null
      },
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      tickLength: 0,
      gridLineColor: '#7F7F7F',
      lineColor: '#7F7F7F',
      categories: {
        '33.33333': 'Må øve mer',
        '66.66667': 'På god vei',
        '100': 'Kan'
      },
      tickPositions: [0, 33.33333, 66.66667, 100],
      plotBands: [{

        from: 31.83333,
        to: 33.33333,
        color: '#CC3333'
      }, {
        from: 65.16667,
        to: 66.66667,
        color: '#F2BA38'
      }, {
        from: 33.33333,
        to: 34.83333,
        color: '#CC3333'
      }, {
        from: 66.66667,
        to: 68.16667,
        color: '#F2BA38'
      }, {
        from: 97,
        to: 100,
        color: '#77B800'
      }]
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: '',
      color: '#646464',
      borderColor: '#464646',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [0, 66.6666666666667, 0, 0]
    }]
  })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ngoclamnn/nu2fwzrn/

But you can see that it has a little bit "weird" at the 0 values, maybe it is a bug on Highchart?

Do you have another way to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "weird"? Do you want to turn the two grid-lines at 0 into a single one?

Comment: Yes!  i dont know why Highchart generate xAxis gridline and yAxis gridline is not the same position at 0 value. If you remove the categories on yAxis, it will be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593883/highcharts-remove-gap-between-start-of-xaxis-and-first-value) I was able to find a solution. Create yAxis categories as a variable and use the same function the answer uses to insert them, that is:

```
 var categories = {0: '', 33.33333: 'Må øve mer', 66.66667: 'På god vei', 100: 'Kan'}
```

And then in the chart:

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return categories[this.value];
    }
  },
  tickInterval: 1,
  minPadding: 0,
  maxPadding: 0,
  startOnTick: true,
  endOnTick: true,
...
}
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/nu2fwzrn/73/

Make sure to upvote [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593883/highcharts-remove-gap-between-start-of-xaxis-and-first-value).

Comment: ah, maybe this can help... those 2 lines is not apprear now, but the labels 'Må øve mer', 'På god vei', 'Kan' are not show on the yAxis. Will try to find out now :)

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I changed the values while testing to be 0, 1, 2, 3 instead of percentages as this is easier to work with. Regardless, I updated the answer now, should work.

Comment: Haha, it's just a small mistake and easy to fix. Thanks a lot ewolden!