# Removing gaps before first and after last columns in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying setup a chart in Decipher - data colleciton platform that uses Highcharts for it dashboards. Even though the syntax is a somewhat different but the logic the same. Could you advise how I can remove these spaces in the image?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCqq.png)

It is a simple bar chart with these options:

- title.text "Leaves your skin feeling really refreshed"
- title.style.minWidth "120px"
- title.style.fontSize "10px"
- title.style.fontWeight "bold"
- title.useHTML true
- title.align "left"
- legend.enabled false
- xAxis.labels.style.fontSize "8px"
- xAxis.labels.useHTML true
- xAxis.visible false
- yAxis.min 0
- yAxis.max 50
- yAxis.visible true
- yAxis.tickInterval 10
- plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter function() {return this.series.name;}
- plotOptions.series.dataLabels.inside true
- plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style.fontSize "8px"
- plotOptions.series.dataLabels.align "left"

I think I've tried all possible margin/padding options and none of the work. It could be that Decipher overrides some Highcharts functionaly but wanted to check here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts remove gap between start of xAxis and first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593883/highcharts-remove-gap-between-start-of-xaxis-and-first-value)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems "plotOptions.series.groupPadding 0" did the trick.