# How to remove a gap in high charts graph with two yAxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I have been trying to get rid of the gap on the left and nothing works. This issues only happens when I add a reverse yAxis on the right. Below is the code I am using:

```
$(function () {
    var categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline',
            zoomType: 'xy',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stats',
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'YTD 2013 - 2014',
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickInterval: 1,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
        },
        yAxis: [{ //--- Primary yAxis
            min: 0,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Mds',
                style: {
                    color: '#8dc63f',
                }
            },
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#8dc63f',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }, { //--- Secondary yAxis


            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var mil = '$';
                    return mil + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#3fb4ed',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Revenue',
                style: {
                    color: '#3fb4ed',
                }

            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'areaspline',
            color: '#005a84',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            yAxis: 0,
            zIndex: 3,
            name: 'Goals',
            data: [5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        }, {
            type: 'areaspline',
            color: '#8dc63f',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            yAxis: 0,
            zIndex: 4,
            name: 'This Year',
            data: [21, 14, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        }, {
            type: 'areaspline',
            color: '#d9531e',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            yAxis: 0,
            zIndex: 3,
            visible: false,
            name: 'Last Year',
            data: [20, 2, 2, 7, 8, 5, 7, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5],
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            color: '#3fb4ed',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            yAxis: 1,
            zIndex: 1,
            visible: false,
            name: 'Revenue',
            data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2]
        }]

    });
});
```

I have tried every possible solutions out there. Went through API docs and searched every forum. Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set for xAxis:

```
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return categories[this.value];
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        min: 0.5,                     // remove padding
        max: categories.length - 1.5, // remove padding
        startOnTick: false,           // allow to start not from tick
        endOnTick: false              // allow to end not at tick
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2EYM/24/ - turn on Revenue - you will see that first and last column will be cut off.

Comment: you have an extra comma after endOnTick: false, This breaks highcharts in older browsers

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is doing this is because, even though the series is hidden on load, you have a column series that needs the width to display. If you just show series "Revenue" you can see it is using that empty space that was there before. You could also play with [`tickPixelInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval) - but for that you need to not use a categorized xAxis.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/LR3p8/).
I also set `showEmpty` to false for both yAxis elements.

Comment: It still look the same. There is a gap on the right and gap on the left.

Comment: I tried setting min: 0.5 and max: 10.5 for xAxis but that make my first value (Jan [0]) disappear and I can't use the tooltip

Comment: Maybe try `offset`. This will move the labels closer and will visually make it look less spread out...sort of. I cant think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the last of series from

```
    type: 'column',
```

to

```
    type: 'areaspline',
```

there will be no gaps on left and right side. Do you need type `column`?

Solution for your problem is answered here [Highcharts Remove Space across the x-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862662/highcharts-remove-space-across-the-x-axis) by user Dusty. You have to setup for x-axis:

```
    min: 0.5,
    max: 10.5,
```

**Note:** if you turn your `column` type series to `visible: true` half of the first and the last column will be cut-off.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it has to be a column. I saw that using areasplin would solve the problem but it looses the effect I want.

Comment: Is there a way to maybe just shift the other 3 areasplins so they start at the beginning of the column bars instead of middle? I could live with that.

Comment: You have to push 12 columns into available 11. It seems that you have exactly 0.5 of column on left and right side.

Comment: how do I do that? i tried [min:0.5, max:10.5,] on xAxis and that just shifted everything left.

Comment: If I found something I'll let you know. I'm not sure if that is possible because you need space for columns. What if you move x-axis ticks to the right for 0.5 width of column so that last tick falls on the right edge.

Comment: pointPadding helped with make it look better. I am still trying to figure out how to move the tick to start on the left instead of center.