# Highcharts padding issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to make a column chart with no padding on the sides.

What options do I have to add to my highcharts configuration?

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytfYe/) is my current attempt:

```
$('#container').highcharts
  series: [{
     data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
      }]
  credits:
    enabled: off
  legend:
    enabled: off
  exporting:
    enabled: off
  title:
    text: null
  chart:
    margin: [0,0,0,0]
    type: 'column'
  plotOptions:
    column:
      groupPadding: 0
      pointPadding: 0
      borderWidth : 0
      stacking: 'normal'
   xAxis:
      title:
        text: null
      labels:
        enabled: off
   yAxis:
      title:
        text: null
      labels:
        enabled: off
      gridLineWidth: 0
      minorGridLineWidth: 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **CoffeeScript**

Under xAxis, add

```
    min: 0.05
    max: 11
```

For Javascript,

Under xAxis, add

```
    min: 0.05,
    max: 11,
```

**P.S.** Adjust `max` according to your needs.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/ytfYe/2/

Ref: [Highcharts Remove Space across the x-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862662/highcharts-remove-space-across-the-x-axis)

tag: bar column left right spacing remove

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why the margin is there despite you setting it zero, but I got rid of it with this:

```
margin: [0,-5,0,-5]
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work if you resize the result window.

Comment: Hmm, it does for me in the fiddle…?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I wasn’t resizing enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minPadding/maxPadding` as 0 on the xAxis.

http://jsfiddle.net/ytfYe/3/